# why image unlink works when condition false

Tags: php, html

I have a form that can either add icon or a icontext. The problem is, that icon is unlinked from file path when I submit form without change.

[image]

```
if (isset($_POST['icontext'])) { // echo '<pre>';print_r($_POST['icontext']);exit;  
    if(file_exists(UPLOAD_PATH . 'images/highlights_icon/' . $this->view->highlights['highlighticon'] )) {  
        unlink(UPLOAD_PATH . 'images/highlights_icon/' . $this->view->highlights['highlighticon']);
        //echo '<pre>';print_r($this->view->highlights['highlighticon']);exit;           
    }
}
```

Comment: maybe you want `!empty($_POST['icontext'])` instead of isset? `icontext` could/will be set even if it's an empty string.

Comment: You might want to consider accepting an answer if it helped you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want to check whether `$_POST['icontext']` is empty or not, instead of checking whether it `is_set` or not, because it might be set even if it's only an empty string.

So change your code to

```
if (!empty($_POST['icontext'])) {
   //...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

if **(!empty**($_POST['icontext'])) {
      if(file_exists(UPLOAD_PATH . 'images/highlights_icon/' . $this->view->highlights['highlighticon'] )) {  unlink(UPLOAD_PATH . 'images/highlights_icon/' . $this->view->highlights['highlighticon']);

```
  }
}
```